# Loading a User Control Onto Form return error every time program is built

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Hello im creating a media player program on visual studio using vb.net. A basic feature of my application is a simple GUI navigation system, in which the user can select tabs such as 'Home' and 'upload' and a different page will show on each one. To do this i have created user controls, in which i load onto my main form and simply turn visibility to false when not selected.

The problem is i having been getting errors everytime the program is built/ i close and reopen the program.

> The designer cannot process unknown name 'BackColor' at line 324. The code within the method 'InitializeComponent' is generated by the designer and should not be manually modified. Please remove any changes and try opening the designer again.

Viewing this code directs to this chunk-

```
'
    'Uploader_Control2
    '
    Me.Uploader_Control2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(CType(CType(24, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(24, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(24, Byte), Integer))
    Me.Uploader_Control2.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill
    Me.Uploader_Control2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(248, 23)
    Me.Uploader_Control2.Name = "Uploader_Control2"
    Me.Uploader_Control2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(1180, 656)
    Me.Uploader_Control2.TabIndex = 0
    '
    'Home_Control2
    '
    Me.Home_Control2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(CType(CType(24, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(24, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(24, Byte), Integer))
    Me.Home_Control2.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill
    Me.Home_Control2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(248, 23)
    Me.Home_Control2.Name = "Home_Control2"
    Me.Home_Control2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(1180, 656)
    Me.Home_Control2.TabIndex = 1
    '
    'Uploader_Control1
    '
    Me.Uploader_Control1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(CType(CType(24, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(24, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(24, Byte), Integer))
    Me.Uploader_Control1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
    Me.Uploader_Control1.Name = "Uploader_Control1"
    Me.Uploader_Control1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(1180, 656)
    Me.Uploader_Control1.TabIndex = 0
    '
    'Home_Control1
    '
    Me.Home_Control1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(CType(CType(24, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(24, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(24, Byte), Integer))
    Me.Home_Control1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
    Me.Home_Control1.Name = "Home_Control1"
    Me.Home_Control1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(1180, 656)
    Me.Home_Control1.TabIndex = 0
```

Deleting this chunk of code removes the error and shows the user controls in my form how i want them. Its starting to become a persistent and annoying issue and despite researching it i have struggled to find any information on how to fix it.

In addition to this loading any of the user controls like this returns a error-

```
Private Sub Uploader_Control2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Uploader_Control2.Load

End Sub
```

> Event load cannot be found

All help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You created a custom control?  Did you follow these steps, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/creating-a-wf-control-design-time-features ?

Comment: Depending which version of VS you're running there was a known issue that toggling the framework may fix: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/160241/errors-reported-when-none-exist.html

Comment: @NathanChampion I have seen the article and unfortunatley neither of the solutions worked. Any other ideas?

Comment: By chance, Backcolor is the first property set for each control. If you comment out that line, the error will move to the next line. Chances are that the namespace or class name for the user control is mispelled, or was changed between the time the user control was firstly consumed in the form and now. Also, if rebuilding the app causes the user control to be rebuilt as part of the same solution, the .dll will be cleaned up before being recompiled.  That's where the errors are coming while recompiling.

Comment: @Lupe_99 If I assume that you created a custom control.did you inherit UserControl?

Comment: Sorry i am really new to this you will have to be patient.  @dbasnett im not sure, how do i do that?

Comment: @Lupe_99 - did you look at the link I  posted?  It shows the basics for creating a user control.

Comment: How about using the tab control and placing regular controls on each tab.